# What is the process state when pthread_mutex() is executed

Tags: linux-kernel, process-management, synchronization, pthreads

Following are the Linux Process states;

```
R: running or runnable, it is just waiting for the CPU to process it
S: Interruptible sleep, waiting for an event to complete, such as input from the terminal
D: Uninterruptible sleep, processes that cannot be killed or interrupted with a signal, usually to make them go away you have to reboot or fix the issue
Z: Zombie, we discussed in a previous lesson that zombies are terminated processes that are waiting to have their statuses collected
T: Stopped, a process that has been suspended/stopped
```

I have two questions;

(1) When a mutex_lock() is called in a process/thread, and if it is waiting for the lock to acquire(another thread locked the mutex already), will the process go to `S` or `D`?

(2) I know that spinlock() will put the process in busy waiting and it checks to see if the lock is unlocked by other thread. However in mutex_lock() how it knows that the lock is unlocked and it is available to lock and proceed? i.e; How the process wakes up from `sleep` to lock the mutex when it is available(unlocked by other thread)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's find out:

```c
#include <pthread.h>                                                            
#include <sys/types.h>                                                          
#include <unistd.h>                                                             
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
int main ()                                                                     
{                                                                               
    pthread_mutex_t    mtx;                                                     
    pid_t              pid;                                                     
    pthread_mutex_init (&mtx, NULL);                                            
                                                                                   
    pid = getpid();                                                                
    printf ("pid : %d\n", pid);                                                    
                                                                                   
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mtx);                                                     
    // Double lock. This results in a dead-lock
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mtx);                                                     
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&mtx);                                                  
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -lpthread -o prog prog.c
```

And then run:

```
./prog

pid : 23537
```

(This is the pid in my particular case. Your run will result in a different one)

Now let's find out the state of this process:

```
ps aux | grep 23537

user      23537  0.0  0.0   6448   840 pts/4    S+   16:29   0:00 ./prog
```

The **S+** is the state of the process.

According to the man page

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
   Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a
   process:

           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped by job control signal
           t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:

           <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
           N    low-priority (nice to other users)
           L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
           s    is a session leader
           l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
           +    is in the foreground process group
```

So it is *interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete) in the foreground process group*

Regarding your second question: when a thread tries to get a mutex that is already locked, the kernel removes that thread from the CPU and stores it in a queue. When the owner releases the lock, the kernel looks if there are any threads in the queue, and wakes them up (maybe).

This is different from a spinlock. A spinlock would be something similar to:

```c
int lock = 1;
// 1 means locked, 0 means unlocked
while (lock) {};
// If we are here, it means the lock somehow changed to 0
lock = 1;
// We set it to one again to avoid another thread taking it
```

But this implementation is not atomic. The kernel provides some means to do this atomically.